# How to broadcast the IP 255.255.255.255 using NWConnectionGroup in Swift?

Tags: swift, multicast

The current documentation https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=0oi77447 states the use of multicast for broadcasting the message.

I created the host as below, But it throws that its not multicast address range.

```
var connection: NWConnection?
var hostUDP: NWEndpoint.Host = "255.255.255.255"
var portUDP: NWEndpoint.Port = portNumber
```

How exactly we can broadcast the above IP address using NWConnectiongroup

Comment: Hi. any update about this? Please check this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669342. may be relevant to you

Comment: thanks I ll have a quick look @Vidu